# Android Studio TextView Length increase

Tags: android, android-studio

I know, the topic may sound a little stupid, but I've got a very long text in a textview. Let's imagine this: Someone falls asleep on the keyboard and a long text appears after the android:text and the length of this is now about 500 letters. Android studio now limits the 500 letters to for example 200. I want it to keep all the letters.

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/twDeutscherBund"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Um eine neue europäische Friedensverordnung in Europa ins Leben zu rufen wurde auf dem Wiener Kongress am 8. Juni 1815 der Deutsche Bund gegründet. Der Bund bestand zwischen 1815 und 1866 mit [...]"
```

that's what is in my TextView. Any ideas how I can display the whole text? I hope I was able to explain it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `android:layout_height="240dp"` to  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Try to get Strings from `string.xml`

Comment: Changing the layout height to wrap_content did the job. I owe you :)

Answer (score 0):

keep your text in strings.xml and use it your .xml layout

**String.xml**

```
<string name="message">**
Google is an American multinational technology company specializing in Internet-related services and products that include online advertising technologies, search, cloud computing, and software
</string>
```

**In your Layout**

```
 android:text="@string/message"

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I wanted to do that though I was too stupid to access the files from strings.xml, may you share how you do dat ._. nvm it's here already~

Comment: String.xml
 <string name="messageStr">your strin</string>
In your layout
 android:text="@string/messageStr"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

```
 String.xml
 <string name="Message">Um eine neue europäische Friedensverordnung in Europa ins Leben zu rufen wurde auf dem Wiener Kongress am 8. Juni 1815 der Deutsche Bund gegründet. Der Bund bestand zwischen 1815 und 1866 mit</string>

 android:text="@string/Message"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`android:ellipsize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) attribute,

> If set, words that are longer than the view is wide to be ellipsized instead of broken in the middle.

Like,

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```